# Should a user comments be more easily searchable?

Tags: feature-request, comments, search

It might only be me, but when I want to find a question I commented on (say, asking for more information / suggesting an idea), I have to try and remember the words which appeared in the question so I could search for it.

Shouldn't a user comments be accessible from the profile for example?

(If there's a simple way of doing so which I'm not aware of, please enlighten me :) ).

Comment: User profile, "Activity", "Comments"?

Comment: I want to be able to find my comments on questions, that's all :).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113621/add-ability-to-search-comments-only and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183142/ability-to-search-comments-would-be-useful